# Automated numbering of questions and solutions

Tags: numbering, exsheets, answers

I'm working on a textbook with sections and subsections, where some subsections are dedicated to exercises.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\section{First!}
\subsection{Some theorems}
Theorem I guess...
\subsection{Exercises}
\begin{enumerate}
\item How much is 1+1?
\item How much is 2+3?
\end{enumerate}

\section{Second!}
\subsection{Let's define something}
A natural number is a number different from a fraction.
\subsection{More theorems}
I like fractions.
\subsection{Exercises}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Is $\pi$ a natural number?
\item Do you like natural numbers?
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to add the solutions in the code and have them gathered for a solutionfile. I know packages like `answers` and `exsheets` can do a good job, but I would like to keep the lay-out of the questions, while having one large solution-file, with automated numbering (in which it is clear which answer corresponds with which question).

Preferably something like

[image]

Keep in mind the number of exercises per subsection can be more then 10, so I'd like to keep my solutions (in code) close to the questions.

Comment: The tricky bit is that things like \thesection need to be expanded immediately and things like \textbf  or \hspace* should not be expanded.  This is usually accomplished using \string or \protected.  Alternatively, one can predefine a number of formats and simply pass an indicator.

Comment: @JohnKormylo How can I predefine those formats to get my result?

Comment: Book defines section as `\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}`  One can find a listing of \@startsection in source2e.pdf from CTAN.  The arguments control the indentation, vertical spacing and font used.  For a single paragraph, one can fake enumerate using `\noindent\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{...}\hspace{\labelsep}\parbox{\dimexpr \textwidth-\labelwidth-\labelsep}{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been tinkering with some settings and the `answers` package, and have settled for the following solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{opdr}{Opdrachten}{ans}
\Newassociation{opl}{Oplossing}{ans}
\renewenvironment{Opdrachten}[1]{\begin{trivlist}\item \bfseries \large #1}{\end{trivlist}}
\renewenvironment{Oplossing}[1]{\begin{enumerate}\item[\bfseries #1.]}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans]
\section{First!}
\subsection{Some theorems}
Theorem I guess...

\subsection{Opdrachten}\label{Opdr_First1}
\begin{opdr}p.\pageref{Opdr_First1}\end{opdr}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item How much is 1+1?
        \begin{opl}
        2
        \end{opl}
    \item How much is 2+3?
        \begin{opl}
        5
        \end{opl}
\end{enumerate}

\section{Second!}
\subsection{Let's define something}
A natural number is a number different from a fraction.
\subsection{More theorems}
I like fractions.

\subsection{Opdrachten}\label{Opdr_Second1}
\begin{opdr}p.\pageref{Opdr_Second1}\end{opdr}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Is $\pi$ a natural number?
        \begin{opl}
            Yes.
        \end{opl}
    \item Do you like natural numbers?
        \begin{opl}
            No.
        \end{opl}
    \item This question doesn't have an answer.

    \item This question does.
        \begin{opl}
            Yeah.
        \end{opl}
\end{enumerate}

\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\newpage
\section*{Oplossingen}
\input{ans}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I like the lay-out, plus, I was able to include the page numbers.

[image]